# Sync folder in docker image from Jhipster

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jhipster, docker-for-windows

I use **Jhipster** from docker under **Window**.

I follow the [tuto](https://jhipster.github.io/installation/) but **I can't synchronize my change in the docker image**.

I want to have my own image from jhipster. I create new one

```
general03@L3F2GPK1F9W0 MINGW64 ~/jhipster/app/src/main/docker
$ docker build -t general03-jhipster .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 5.632 kB
Step 1 : FROM jhipster/jhipster
 ---> 0ae13f5d5a79
Step 2 : ADD . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a8aaf63bf7e
Step 3 : ENV JHIPSTER_SLEEP 0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 67a9ab5ce70a
Step 4 : ADD *.war /app.war
No source files were specified
```

In my Dockerfile I copied the original jhipster Dockerfile and replace first line and `ADD . /app`

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

ADD . /app

ENV JHIPSTER_SLEEP 0

# add directly the war
ADD *.war /app.war

RUN sh -c 'touch /app.war'
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
CMD echo "The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s..." && \
    sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} && \
    java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war
```

And I see the image with `docker images` but without **REPOSITORY** and **TAG** !
So when I try to launch `docker run 67a9ab5ce70a` I have this error

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: No command specified.docker run 67a9ab5ce70a
```

**Somebody can help me to push my local modification to the docker images ?**

Comment: Can you provide the output of your docker build command?

Comment: Show your Dockerfile, particularly the lines with CMD or ENTRYPOINT, if you specify nothing in those 2 directives, you need to add some command to your `docker run 67` , a shell or anything

Answer (score 0):

when you say

```
docker build -t general03-jhipster .
```

it means "**build** a docker image with the name **general03-jhipster** based on a docker file, located in **.**"

So you should generally run it with `docker run general03-jhipster`, but without arguments, this won't work until you provide port bindings

for the default JHipster configuration and **dev profile**

you should run

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 general03-jhipster
```

If this fails, you propably starting in prod mode, so it needs some database binding. Passing this in command line can get up messy. Here you should take a look to JHipsters [Docker compose support](https://jhipster.github.io/docker-compose/), to use docker compose to manage all your databases, elasticsearch instances etc..

**edit**: I didn't noticed the error first time here

```
Step 4 : ADD *.war /app.war
No source files were specified
```

So it's easy, you didn't generate a war file, so obvious the docker build fails.

Use

```
./mvnw package -Pprod docker:build
```

or

```
./gradlew build -Pprod bootRepackage buildDocker
```

to generate a proper docker build.

If you want to change some docker specific thinks (and using gradle), you can change this in "gradle/docker.gradle"

Comment: Thanks to your answer, but I think my mistake is on dockerfile. Is it well written ?

Comment: Yes you're right about **step 4**, I founded the issue. And for you the **step 2** is right ? I think it's rather `COPY ../../../app /app` , no ?

Comment: No. The dockerfile is copied via the maven/gradle task in the correct folder. I suggest always to use the build task over manual docker commands. As you tried to do this manually, it failed, as our docker files assume a different configuration, which is provided in the build task

Comment: Can you give me an example please, I'm beginner

Comment: just change your code, and as soon you want to have a new docker image, run the commands I mentioned above, depending on your choice by maven or gradle. Do this command inside your projects root directory. When this succeeds, you will get a new "general03-jhipster" image, which you then can start.

Comment: Would you recommand me to delete `ADD . /app` from dockerfile and prefer used my builder `./mvnw` to copy local files in my container ?

Comment: Now I can launch my app with your maven build command and after launch docker-compose. **But I don't see my java update code in the application !** How can I do ?

Comment: I only need to know how to synchronize my local file with container, please